# Euler-Poincare characteristic for relative schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, sheaf-cohomology, coherent-sheaves

Let $X\to S$ a morphism of Noetherian schemes. Assume that $\mathcal F$ is a coherent sheaf on $X$ with the following property: **the support of $\mathcal F$ is proper over a subscheme of $S$ of dimension $0$**. Then I've read in Kollar's book "Rational curves on algebraic varieties (chap VI appendix 2)", that in this case it is possibile to define the Euler-Poincare characteristic $\chi_S(\mathcal F)$. This is quite weird because I've seen the Euler-Poincare characteristic only for algebraic varieties.

What is $\chi_S$? I suppose that is the alternating sum of the lengths of cohomologies where somehow we use the properties of Artinian modules. Can you please explain the construction in details?

Comment: By "the support is proper over a subscheme" do you mean (call $Y$ the support) that there is $S_0$ such that $Y$ maps to $S_0$ and $Y \rightarrow S_0$ is proper or that $Y|_{S_0}$ is proper ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. If $g: X \to S$ is proper and the $R^ig_*\mathcal{F}$ have $0$-dimensional support, say at $s$, then one can take the length of the $R^ig_*\mathcal{F}$  and their alternating sum.

Comment: Sorry I had forgotten to accept your answer.